# disabled certs by System.property not working correct with expected result

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have problem with disable certs in code. In code:

```
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            builder.build());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(
            sslsf).build();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://interkar.pl/bok/");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    try {
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    }
    finally {
        response.close();
    }
```

then throw exception:

```
  javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
```

But if i add to intellij in runner this:

```
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

then i get expected result, but how to resolve in code ?

i use java 8 and HttpClient is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```